# Formulas to diagonally divide a square in four triangles

Tags: geometry

I'm working with discret numbers (integers) and I'm looking for 4 sets of formulas to determine within which of these 4 triangles an $(x;y)$ point is, with $x \in [0;36[$ and $y \in [0;36[$.

[image: Easier to understand with this]

Comment: What have you done so far?

Comment: So far I found (for the grid starting in the bottom left corner) x < 18 && y < 18 && x > y but it's only for the left part of the yellow triangle..

Comment: Okay I found my out I'll post when I finish it

Comment: How do you deal with the points on the boundaries? Like $(1,0)$ or $(1,1)$. To which triangle do they belong?

Answer (score 0):

$$(x,y) \in {\rm red\ if}\ |y-x|> -1 \wedge |y+x| < 36$$

Can you continue?